# FileProvider.getUriForFile doesn't save image to gallery and can't access file OnActivityResult

Tags: android, android-camera

In my app, trying to capture images using the camera app. 
I am updating my app to use FileProvider.getUriForFile when specifying the file path to save images to, as Uri.fromFile is deprecated.

It was working fine beforehand using Uri.fromFile. But I can't get it to work using FileProvider.getUriForFile.

I am creating the image file as follows:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
            );

            mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
            return image;
```

Then, depending on the target sdk, I get the image URI:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            jobImageURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                        } else {
                            jobImageURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(OrderDetails.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",photoFile);
                        }
```

I have updated the app manifest xml to include the provider, as per the android developer documentation.
I have a provider_paths.xml file which holds the path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Then I launch the camera:

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, jobImageURI);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

However, after the photo is taken and it comes back to the onActivityResult function, I read back in the image file.
The image isn't saved to the Gallery, as I am reading back in the last file from the Gallery but it isn't there.
I can't access the file using the path from the jobImageURI above either.

Is the path I've provided the provider_paths.xml file incorrect, or why can't I access the images?

Comment: provide path in place of dot(.) at xml.

Comment: don't forget to register provider in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: thank you Aniruddh. 
how do i know what the path is?

i have registered the provider in the AndroidManifest.xml:
<provider
 android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this way**

create a xml file under `xml` folder in `res` directory

> provider_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/yourAppPackageName/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Register Provider in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="yourAppPackageName.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_path"/>
        </provider>
```

> add these permissions

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

> on Camera Button Click call `dispatchTakePictureIntent()`

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                        "com.arantico.servicepro.provider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }




    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

here `mCurrentPhotoPath`  will show the path of file where it got stored

Comment: Thanks. But when I change the path in the xml to your suggestion, I am now getting the following error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20181120_151734_7133607314068675624.jpg

Comment: I have already registered the Provider in the AndroidManifest.xml as you specified.

Comment: my path in the provider_paths xml file is now: <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.arantico.servicepro/files/Pictures" />. "com.arantico.servicepro" is the app package name.

Comment: yes, android:authorities="com.arantico.servicepro.provider"

Comment: i changed: 
File storageDir =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
to be:             
File storageDir =  getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

and no longer get the "failed to find configured root" error. 
But when I try to access the file after using the path built up 
(file:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.arantico.servicepro/files/Pictures/JPEG_20181120_154733_4851809345196878770.jpg), it still doesn't exist.

Comment: check updated answer, if you found path error then you can provide existing path or create the specific one using file.mkdirs().

Comment: i hope updated code will work if you added run-time permission check.

Comment: yes, your answer above is working now. thanks very much!